# Is it possible to use placeholder in WP7 (PhoneGap)?

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, placeholder

I have been making an app using Apache Cordova (formerly known as PhoneGap), and I have input fields with the `placeholder` attribute.

This works fine on Android and iOS, but not Windows Phone 7.

I know you can use JavaScript to emulate the same functionality, but I want to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Is it possible to use `placeholder` on Windows Phone 7 in input elements? If so, how do use it?

Answer (score 2):

The placeholder is an HTML5 element. Apparently WP7 browser does not recognize this yet.